# Python tkinter error messages

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, tkinter

I have an application spread across several modules that consists of a main module, a UI, a processing function and a module to hold the global variables. I'm having problems with tkinter throwing error messages, but I don't understand why, and I think the route cause may be unrelated to tkinter (possibly to do with threading?).

A simplification of the application that exhibits the same issues is as follows:

**mymain.py**

```
import math
import random
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox

import myui
import myfunction
import myglobals

root = Tk()

myglobals.ui = myui.UI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

**myfunction.py**

```
import thread
import random

import myglobals
import myui

def myfunc():
    multiprint(str(random.random()))
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunc,())



def multiprint(*args):
    msg = ' '.join([str(arg) for arg in args])
    print msg
    if myglobals.ui:
        myglobals.ui.writeToLog(msg)
```

**myui.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox
import types
import time
import random

import myfunction

class UI:


    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master

        #top frame

        self.topframe = Frame(self.master)
        self.topframe.pack(fill=X)

        self.button = Button(self.topframe, text="Start", command=self.startgame)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)


        #event frame

        self.logframe = Frame(self.master)
        self.logframe.pack(fill=X)

        self.logframetitle = Label(self.logframe, text="Event log:")
        self.logframetitle.pack(fill=X)

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.log = Text(self.master, state='disabled', height=24, wrap='none', yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.log.pack(fill=X)

        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.log.yview)


    def startgame(self):
        myfunction.myfunc()

    def writeToLog(self,msg):
        numlines = self.log.index('end').split('.')[0] #self.log.index('end - 1 line') gives the start of the last line of text
        print 'The log is', numlines, 'long'
        self.log['state'] = 'normal'
        if self.log.index('end-1c')!='1.0':
            self.log.insert('end', '\n')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.log.insert('end', msg)
        self.log['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.log.see('end')



def main():

    root = Tk()

    ui = UI(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**myglobals.py** is a blank file that holds the variables.

The error messages I'm getting include the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2860, in set
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'set') + args)
TclError: invalid command name "512.14"
```

and

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function myfunc at 0x02940A30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\myfunction.py", line 20, in myfunc
    multiprint(str(random.random()))
  File "C:\myfunction.py", line 29, in multiprint
    myglobals.ui.writeToLog(msg)
  File "C:\myui.py", line 67, in writeToLog
    self.log['state'] = 'disabled'
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1269, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1262, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1253, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".43240984"
```

I am bemused about how to understand these error messages. I've tried googling the message codes, but haven't found anything helpful so far.

Really grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

The error message mentions threads. In the stack trace it looks like you are altering the state of a variable. If that is true, and you're trying to alter the state of a widget from a thread other than the one that created the widget, that's the problem. You cannot call widget methods from any thread except the one that created the widget.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you couldn't do that. I think that probably explains the second error message, but the first doesn't mention threads, so perhaps two separate issues? The interesting thing is that if you run the program, it runs fine most of the time and only occasionally throws errors. That's the bit I don't understand, as the error is not consistent.

Comment: Maybe two separate issues, maybe not. Errors related to thread (non)safety can sometimes be random and hard to understand.